# python selenium inherit webdriver methods

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been looking for a solution to inherit the methods of the python selenium webdriver class so that I can extend/modify its behaviour. I have not found one that work.

For instance, I want to inherit all the methods of the chrome webdriver but extend the .get() method (i.e. the method to load a url). This is my current approach:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exception import TimeoutException

class CustomDriver:

   def __init__(self, browser):
      if browser.lower() == 'chrome'
         self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   
   def get_url(self, url):
      try:
         self.driver.get(url)
      
      except TimeoutException:
         self.driver.quit()
```

This methods works but it does not inherit the general webdriver methods like `driver.quit()`. In fact, if I do the following:

```py
mydriver = CustomDriver('Chrome')
mydriver.quit()
```

I get the error: `'Custom driver' object has no attribute quit`.
Has any of you any suggestions?

ps: I'm new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quit() is from webdriver methods and you are importing it from selenium module, and you have created a object self.driver for the webdriver.Chrome()

so you can't use webdriver method on created class object that is the reason why you are getting No Attribute Error : 'Custom driver' object has no attribute quit

One way of obtaining inheritance is by declaring respective method inside the class and inherit those methods outside.

Refer this document: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-driver-methods-in-selenium-python/

Below is the code that would work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

class CustomDriver:
    def __init__(self, browser):
        if browser.lower() == 'chrome':
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def exit_browser(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def get_url(self, url):
        try:
            self.driver.get(url)
        except TimeoutException:
            self.driver.quit()


mydriver = CustomDriver('Chrome')
mydriver.get_url("https://www.google.com/")
mydriver.exit_browser()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. 
In you example, you build your own custom wrappers (exit_browser) around the webdriver method. 

What do you mean by declare respective method inside the class and inherit those methods? Thanks for your help and time.